Is there a way to improve my R function so that it takes an amino acid string and returns all biologically possible substitutions?
A short example of what I am trying to accomplish:
Starting String Example: VSC
For the output, I am looking for all possible combinations of an amino acid string with specific rules depending on the letter you want to substitute
Potential AA substitutions:
V can only be substituted for L or A and vice versa
S can only be substituted for T and vice versa
C can only be substituted for M and vice versa
Output Data Example:
ASC
LSC
ATC
LTC
ATM
LTM
VSM
VTM
.... and other potential matches
I have thought about using expand.grid or another similar function, but I need more specificity for these substitutions.
I have tried the following code:
string2 <- "VSC"
n2 <- length(unlist(gregexpr("A|L|T|M", string2)))
df2 <- expand.grid(rep(list(c("T","A","L","M)), n2))
string_sub <- gsub("A|L|T|M", "\\%s", string2)
do.call(sprintf, as.list(c(string_sub, df2)))

However, the output does not take into account that, for example, only S and T can be substituted.  I am a little bit lost on how to add these rules in.

In the function, I would only want specific pairs of substitution like between S/T.

Maybe ask on a Bioconductor forum?

I have tried to make a post on the bioconductor forum, but alas, they ask for a specific package name in the question.

This looks promising.
